# Account linking in Actions console : how to get "Google Sign In Client Information" for "Google Sign in" linking type?

Tags: actions-on-google

In Actions console, i try to setup account linking with 'Google Sign in' type :

- in Develop/Account linking menu,
- i have chosen 'Google Sign in' type
- when "Google Sign In Client Information" is displayed, input fields are empty.

I understood that the input fields had to contain 'Authorization URL' and 'Token URL'.
How to get this information to insert it in my code

thanks

Comment: Are you using Google Sign-in, or Google Sign-in/OAuth?

Comment: i want tou use Google Sign-In , as described in https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

Answer (score 0):

**Update October 2019**

Google seems to have updated their Google projects again. You can now see your Client ID under the Google Sign-in option again.

[image]

---

The Authorization URL and Token URL are supposed to be empty. You need to provide the information yourself. The authorization URL and token URL are endpoints that you will build or a OAuth service such as [auth0](https://auth0.com/) that you use to verify the logins from your users to a service.

Comment: I do not think that Authorization URL and Token URL fileds must be empty.

I followed this procedure : https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

and in 'Implement Google Sign-In account linking', paragraph 5, i read : 
"Open Client Information and take note of the value of Client ID issued by Google to your Actions."

Comment: True, Client ID isn't empty, Google will make it for you, but Google does not create a Authorization or Token url for you. You will have to provide those urls yourself. You can do that by using a 0Auth service or hosting your own server which handles the authorization and token logic.

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=0

select your project and check OAuth 2.0 client IDs=> Web client (auto-created by Google Service)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the response of Amol Shiledar, I just understood:
there is no need to consider the Authorization URL and Token URLs fields.

It is enough to get the client Id (as indicated by Amol Shiledar) and to indicate it in the code of the fulfillment:

const app = dialogflow ({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID
});

Now it works well :-)